# One line in UIButton iOS15

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit, ios15

I have issue. I can't set numberOfLines to 1 in UIButton. To setup button I use UIButton.Configuration from iOS 15. This is my button with long text:

[image]

I'd like to set the end of text at end of the button. I've tried to set this commands:

```
parentButton.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
parentButton.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
```

And NSLayoutConstraint

```
        parentButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor,   constant: 12),
        parentButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 25),
        parentButton.rightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -25),
        parentButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: what's the type of the button? Filled?

Comment: Yes. There is Filled.

Comment: The lineBreakMode shouldn't be  .byTruncatingTail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the first two lines you have written above, just change button style to `default`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I mean to stop text at end of the button. I don't need fit all text in button.

Comment: Updating my answer now